# How do I put a space between a picture and a table in HTML when the picture is aligned to the left?

Tags: html, html-table, spacing

I want to put a space between my picture and table but not sure how.

Here is my code..

```
<img src="images/hotel_gracia.jpg" width="200" height="150" align="left"/>
<table class="hotel">
<tr>
<th>Room with Breakfast (P.P)</th>
<th>Superior</th>
<th>Economy</th>
</tr>
<td>12th April-16th April & 5th October-23rd October 2011</td>
<td>42 Euros</td>
<td>37 Euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>26th April-1st June 2011 </td>
<td>50 Euros</td>
<td>42 Euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6th Apr-11th Apr, 17th Apr-25th Apr
2nd Jun-17th Jul & 12th Sept-4th Oct 2011
</td>
<td>55 Euros</td>
<td>45 Euros</td>
</tr>
<td>18th July-11th September 2011</td>
<td>59 Euros</td>
<td>50 Euros</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

At present the table is right next to the picture, I would like a little space between them.

I've used "nbsp;" before but not sure where I put it.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about the CSS box model:

`<img style="margin-right:20px"`

Note: Most will recommend a css class to keep the styles.

Comment: ive got a css sheet, would I put that in the css or the html??

Comment: another thing if i wanted to add a border to my picture can I add that to the image style too??

Answer (score 0):

Separate multiple style settings with semicolons:

```
<img style="margin-right:10px; border: 6px double #545565" 
src="images/hotel_idania.jpg" width="200" height="150" align="left"/>
```

Though you probably want `margin-bottom` instead of `margin-right` because tables are block elements and won't appear on the same line as your image by default.

Comment: excellent, that works a treat! about the margin, it seems to be fine, so i'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style="margin-right:10px; border:6px double #545565"
    src = "images/hotel_idania.jpg" width="200" height="150" align="left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your inline style of  tag. change it as below.

```
<img style="margin-right:10px; border:6px double #545565";
```